# Chrome devtool shortcut for "Pause on Exceptions"?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chromium, chrome-devtools-protocol

[image]

In Chrome devtool source panel, there are 7 buttons, and all of them can be controlled by keyboard shortcuts except the last one " Pause on Exception", Is there any way I can active/deactivate this button by keyboard shortcut? I didn't find the shortcut to control this

Comment: I've been waiting for this for years. And I don't know how it's not a high priority in the dev community. When you've hit an exception and know that it's going to bubble up through 20 or 30 scopes that you have to manually step through.. not being able to 'stop pausing on exceptions' with a shortcut becomes criminal.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at:

- The tooltip for the button
- The list at Settings > Shortcuts in DevTools
- The [official shortcut docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/shortcuts/)

It seems like there isn't a preset shortcut, nor a way to set one.